# Http Request return nothing

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c

I'm trying to learn how to create a http request to a php document and then insert it into a mysql table. The problem is that it does not return anything. No errors and not even a empty row in mysql. What am i doing wrong?

objective-c

```
              NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&id=%@&userid=%@",@"lol", @"2", @"1"];

                NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

                NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
                [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.ratemyplays.com/api/post_user.php"]]];

                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
                [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
                [request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

php code:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("mysql12.gigahost.dk","dirts","password_example","dirts_api");


$name = (string)$_POST['name'];
$id = (int)$_POST['id'];
$userid = (int)$_POST['userid'];



$query = "INSERT INTO User_friends (name, profileID, userID) VALUES ('$name', '$id', '$userid')";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
?>
```

Comment: Get rid of the (string) and (int), if you want you can use settype($name, "string"); and settype($id, "integer");

Comment: Does not change anything.

Comment: Your code is easily susceptible to SQL injection. Check out [`mysqli_prepare`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). You also haven't [`echo`](http://us2.php.net/echo) any content. What do you think should be the output sent to the user?

Answer (score 0):

What about adding submit and then checking with php

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&id=%@&userid=%@submit=",@"lol", @"2", @"1"];


<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])
    {

        $link = mysqli_connect("mysql12.gigahost.dk","dirts","password_example","dirts_api");


        $name = (string)$_POST['name'];
        $id = (int)$_POST['id'];
        $userid = (int)$_POST['userid'];



        $query = "INSERT INTO User_friends (name, profileID, userID) VALUES ('$name', '$id',          '$userid')";
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

        if (!$result)
        {
            die(mysql_error());
       }
    ?>
```

Comment: Nothing. When i go direct to http://ratemyplays.com/api/post_friends.php it adds a empty row. When i run the objective-c code nothing is added to the mysql table. It seems like the objective-c code does not trigger the php query.

Comment: Updated...see if that helps

Comment: the if (isset($_POST['submit']) does not trigger and does not add a row when objective-c code is running. It must be something with the objective-c code. i use this exactly http request elsewhere and it works fine. its strange.